# Get string value from xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing

I have a web service which returns the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">ba7665f2-4548-4f85-9b23-d8979f000722</string>
```

Using jQuery I thought I could do something like `$(response).find('string').text();` to get the string value from my xml.

However this doesn't work and in fact `$(response).find('string').length` equals 0.

How can I use javascript to get the string value from this xml?

Comment: How are you calling "response"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're getting the response text correctly, it's possible you're forgetting to call parseXML before you call find.  Take a look at the sample script on this page

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using $.ajax(), $.post(), or $.get()? If so, try this:

```
var myString = response.d;
```

example:

```
...
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myURL",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {

        var myString = response.d;

    }
    ...
```